# How to create a class variable from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python dict from which I want to create a python object inside a class like the following.

```
my_dict = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}

class A:
    key1 = value1
    key2 = value2
```

Approaches I have tried

1. Using globals method, this method creates a global variables but not on class level this accessing them `A.key1`

```
globals().update(my_dict)
```

2. Tried using class inheritance but this creates an additional variable to access the variable in the class

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
class B(A):
    a = A(**my_dict)
    start_date = 202219
    time = 0
    back_fall = {}
```

If I want to access the `key1` I'm doing the following `B.a.key1`

Comment: Any reason you are trying to come up with some clever solution? Why not a simple class initializer?

Comment: This class will hold all my settings to run an application, but the values will be dynamic when the application is running

Comment: Then... why not just use the dictionary itself? It sounds to me like you're trying to make Python bend over backwards to make it behave like JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

use `self.__dict__` to create attributes inside a class.

here is an example

```
class A:
 def __init__(self,var_name,var_value):
  self.__dict__[var_name]=var_value
```

using this example you can pass your dictionary into your constructor and your constructor should loop through dictionary keys and values and append them to `self.__dict__` accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Python has an inbuilt method called `setattr()` which can be used for dynamic class variable creation. Sample code to implement the above code is as following.

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    setattr(A, key, value)
```